# is fail2ban safe? Better to use ssh keys?

Tags: ssh, fail2ban

I'm in doubt if I should use key authentication when logging into SSH, or just go for fail2ban + ssh (root login disabled).

Is fail2ban safe or is it really better to just go ahead and generate keys and config that on all my client machines that need to connect to ssh?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I judge it as a stable product and I regard it as safe.  As an extra precaution I would add your source IP address to the `ignoreip` directive in the `jails.conf` to make sure you don't block yourself.

Since it parses the ssh logs a TCP session is going to have to be established so spoofing source IPs and getting the TCP sequences numbers right to create a sort of backscatter variation seems unlikely.

Using keys on top of this as well isn't a bad idea. Other options that help are moving ssh to a nonstandard IP, using the "recent" iptables module, or just deciding you don't care if people try to brute force passwords.  See [this serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/17870/hundreds-of-failed-ssh-logins/17874#17874) post for more on these.

Comment: The Fail2Ban directions say not to edit any of the `.conf` files and instead to put your configurations in `.local` files. This also makes upgrades much easier, as none of your local files get overwritten.

Comment: Chris S: Thanks for that tip... I will attempt to make a mental note :-)

Comment: Nonstandard _IP_? You mean _port_, right?

Answer (score 4):

Every time I've ever implemented denyhosts or fail2ban in a production environment it has created a guaranteed ticket-stream of unlock requests, password reset requests, requests to change the settings or manage the whitelist, and generally just people who give up logging in to look into things and lean more on the sysadmins for stuff they could do themselves.

Its not a technical problem with either tool per-se, but if your users number in the dozens or greater its going to be a noticable uptick in support workload and frustrated users.

Also, the problem they solve is they reduce your risk of brute force ssh login attacks.  Honestly, the risk of that is incredibly small as long as you have even a moderately decent password policy.

Comment: On the last server I put online, I had 30k failed login request on my logs... just in three days! Even with a good password policy, just for avoiding that big logs and all that noise and risk it's a nice tool.

I use denyhosts and do a good tweak of the config files and so...

Comment: I put the threshold at 10 failed logins in 10 minutes (for SSH, IMAP, etc) and have never had an authorized user get locked out. the default settings are a bit tight, and users do hit them now and then; higher limits generally only catch brute-forcing attempts; which I agree are unlikely, but I also agree with Andor that it helps with the log size.

Comment: oh no 10mb of wasted disk space

Answer (score 2):

I use since few years and at least is a good protection against script kiddies.
No root logon, plus pretty long and random passwords and fail2ban and maybe different port is for most of us enough secure.
Of course ssh keys are much better as security.

Answer (score 1):

I've run Fail2Ban for a little while now, and just recently I've seen distributed attempts to break in to my SSH server. They'll never succeed at the rate their going, but I've been keeping an eye on it.

They've been going through a dictionary, each IP tries twice, after those attempts fail another IP does the same, etc. I've considered banning IPs that try unknown usernames x times. But so far I've gotten a few thousand different IPs trying to get in; and I'm concerned that even if I block them all there'll still be more.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using denyhosts in several of my production and non-production servers, and it works real fine (I had problems with daemon sync, so I don't use it now, but maybe it's working fine again).

Not only makes your system safer, but it helps you keep cleaner logs and simply keep out undesired people out of your login screens...