# How to limit the number of SSH connection from the SSH Sever

Tags: ssh

Is it possible to limit the number of concurrent SSH connections to server ?

Warm Regards

Supratik

Comment: What SSH server? On what operating system?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hundreds of failed ssh logins.](http://serverfault.com/questions/17870/hundreds-of-failed-ssh-logins)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sleske is mostly right. You can set the maximum number of *unauthenticated* connections to `sshd` with `MaxStartups` (see `sshd_config(5)`) but that won't affect the number of *authenticated* connections.

You could, however, restrict the number of overall connections to `sshd` with a packet filter like Netfilter (`iptables`) using the `connlimit` extension.

Example (slightly modified directly from `iptables(8)`):

```
# limit the number of parallel SSH requests to 16 per class C sized network (24 bit netmask)
iptables -p tcp --syn --dport 22 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 16 --connlimit-mask 24 -j REJECT
```

Comment: Given the prevalence of ssh attacks on the internet you could end up DOSing yourself unless you also include a whitelist (if known). Might be a good idea to run fail2ban or similar as well.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, at least the SSH server from OpenSSH (which is the default on most Linux/Unix systems) does not have this option.

Maybe you could explain why you feel this limit to be necessary? There might be a better way to solve your problem.