# Throttle Logins to Linux System

Tags: ssh, login

How can I set login throttling and lockout policies on a Linux (specifically Debian) system?

Things like, setting retry count, delays between login attempts, and idle session timeouts.

The box in question is a headless server, so SSH settings are acceptable.
Thanks!

Comment: See: http://serverfault.com/questions/17870/hundreds-of-failed-ssh-logins/17879#17879

Answer (score 2):

On my DMZ box...

```
# cat /etc/debian_version 
5.0.4
```

I primarily use a combination of [DenyHosts](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/faq.html) and SSHD configuration tweaks to accomplish those things, which are obviously heavily dependent on your particular goals.  For security reasons, I'm not inclined to post my denyhosts.conf file - but the FAQ (linked herein) should hit on a few of your questions quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Matt's recommendations are sensible - but you should also have a look at how [pam is configured](http://aplawrence.com/Basics/understandingpam.html).

Note that this is not the way to prevent completely unauthorized system access - for that you need to have a look at the sshd config, firewall, [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), and possibly 2-factor authentication.