# iptables to drop for a while IPs with recently failed connections

Tags: iptables, linux-networking

I want to decrease the likelihood of a successful ssh attack on a linux system. The only port that is open is 22 (I use port forwarding for everything else), and of course I made sure that ssh accepts only key-pair-based logins (no passwords).

The volume of failed ssh login attempts (output of `last -f /var/log/btmp`) was fairly large (as anybody opening up port 22 should expect), so for the last 2+ years I've been relying on a variation af the iptables-based solutions often mentioned to block ssh attacks, for example [Hundreds of failed ssh logins](https://serverfault.com/a/17879/146786).

One annoying drawback of such a scheme is that it limits the number of new connections from an ip address per amount of time, no matter whether previous connections from that ip were successful or not and whether they were trying to log in as the same user or not.  Imagine a script containing half a dozen of `rsync` commands used from abroad to update various areas on that server: it typically hits the "new connection limit" and fails somewhere in the middle. The same goes if several users behind a router (showing up as the same IP address) do connect on my server more or less at the same time.

So, I am wondering if, **without resorting to parsing the `/var/log` files**, it is possible to implement the following strategy with `iptables`:

1. accept established connections
2. allow new connections from previously successful connections
3. put IPs with failed connections in jail for some time

Bonus points:

1. Same as above, but allowing/jailing specific `user@ip` instead of everybody `@ip`.

And to attempt to curb botnet attacks:

1. Temporarily put in jail a user (no matter which IP (s)he connects from) after a failed ssh attempt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without parsing logfiles, you can't know if an ssh login attempt was succesful. Fortunately you don't have to parse those logfiles yourself. [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) can do this for you. I generally jail an IP for a week after 3 failed login attempts.

Answer (score 2):

**2020 Update**

Nowadays I just use `sshguard` (on containers) or `fail2ban` with `ipset` (vm's / bare metal) - all with public key `ssh` listening on a non standard port. I still limit access to this port with `iptables` to my static ip's. My `fail2ban` config blocks attackers for 2 days with `bantime  = 48h`. I still use a `vpn` but am switching to `wireguard`.

See also:

- [SSH Hardening](https://infosec-handbook.eu/blog/wss1-basic-hardening/#s3) to add 2 Factor Authentication
- [Onlykey SSH setup](https://docs.crp.to/openssh.html) to put your `ssh` keys onto a Security Key. It
  also works with `gpg` keys. It is much more secure than having your private keys on your pc. It is physically more secure than a Yubikey due to **Onlykey** being **PIN protected**.
- [How to back up your 2FA secret keys with KeePassXC](https://blog.paranoidpenguin.net/2020/05/how-to-back-up-your-2fa-secret-keys-with-keepassxc/)
- Use a disposable [Qubes](https://www.qubes-os.org/) vm for generating your keys

I also use Onlykey to secure [KeepassXC](https://keepassxc.org/docs/#faq-yubikey-2fa) as a `HMAC-SHA1` 2nd Factor. It can also be used with Linux PAM to login to your system & be required for `sudo`.

With this setup I do not worry about `ssh` being exploited.

---

First of all **do not** have `ssh` listen on `port 22` to reduce the chance of your port being found by automated scanners.

Also use `psad` to [automatically block hosts which scan your machine](http://cipherdyne.org/psad/index.html) for a configurable amount of time (1 hour by default).

A very simple solution is to just rent a `64 or 128 meg` `openvz` container & [configure `openvpn`](http://chschneider.eu/linux/server/openvpn.shtml) so you have a `fixed ip address` & then limit your `iptables` rule to `--source vpn.ip.address` on the host you wish to protect.

A better solution is to completely stealth your `ssh` port with[`fwknop`](http://cipherdyne.org/fwknop/). There is then no need to run `fail2ban` as your `ssh` port is closed until you send a `gpg` signed & encrypted packet from the `fwknop-client` which will open your firewall for a configurable amount of time (30 seconds by default). You can also configure `fwknop` to only accept certain ip addresses (such as your `vpn`).

I have some quite [extensive notes here](http://it-offshore.co.uk/security/53-stealth-your-ssh-port-ssh-into-lxc-containers) for `fwknop`.

If you are serious about `ssh` security you should also be using `ed25519` keys. More notes here for using [secure ciphers with `openssh`](http://it-offshore.co.uk/security/51-alpine-linux-chrooted-sftp-secure-ssh-ciphers). Another a good choice is [`tinyssh`](http://tinyssh.org/) which has **no** dependency on `openssl` & is [secure by default](http://it-offshore.co.uk/linux/alpine-linux/52-alpine-linux-tinyssh-secure-by-default).

All of the software mentioned here exists in [Alpine Linux](http://alpinelinux.org/) which also benefits from [address space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization#Linux) via `PaX` in it's [Grsecurity](https://grsecurity.net/) kernel.

Comment: Aw. The site showing your notes seems to be down (in early December 2020). Have you placed them somewhere else? It'll be very kind of you to update the links to your resources...