# Need help translating rate limiting iptables rules to Puppet format

Tags: iptables, puppet

I use Puppet Iptables module to manage Iptables rules on my machine.
I'd like to implement to rate limit failed SSH connections as described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/17870/hundreds-of-failed-ssh-logins/17879#17879):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 5 --name SSH --rsource -j DROP 
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m recent --set --name SSH --rsource -j ACCEPT
```

Is it possible to translate it to Puppet syntax, such as

```
firewall { '015 drop 5 failed attemps to connect to SSH in a minute ':
   proto   => 'tcp',
   port    => 22,
   action  => 'drop',
   // what are the other paramters ?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [puppetlabs-firewall](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-firewall/blob/master/lib/puppet/type/firewall.rb) module tries hard to support all `iptabels` arguements. The `recent` specific arguements are prefixed with a single `r`, e.g. `rseconds` instead of `--seconds`.

Try

```
firewall { '015 drop 5 failed attemps to connect to SSH in a minute ':
    proto   => 'tcp',
    port    => 22,
    action  => 'drop',
    recent  => 'update',
    rseconds  => '60',
    rhitcount => '5',
    rname     => 'SSH',
    rsource   => true,
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! The syntax works but it seems it's not dropping five failed SSH connections. I put it in my pre.pp firewall file, I tried before and after the rule that accepts tcp on port 22. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Well, if your rules won't do what you expect, you should ask that as a new question. If the manifest works for you, then you can probably close this one.