# Does it exist a fail2ban alternative in official Centos repository?

Tags: centos, fail2ban

If I don't want to add other repository (epel for example) than the official ones that are coming with a fresh Centos install, is there a more official alternative than fail2ban?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/17879/37681

Comment: EPEL is pretty widely used and respected so I wouldn't worry because it doesn't come with a warranty.