# Rate limit SSH public key failures

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I'm trying to rate limit the number of failed SSH logins on my server. It is set up not to accept any passwords, and accepts PubKeyAuth

Is there a way to rate limit the number of bad logins I get from a user? Like if I see a lot of

```
Feb 12 20:58:55 sshd[...]: Failed publickey for ...
```

Can I do something like limit that to X attempts every Y mins?
I tried using PAM, but it looks like it is used only for password based auth

Comment: Similar https://serverfault.com/q/17870/984

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `UsePAM yes` PAM is used even when using key-based authentication but only the account and session modules.

However, I'd suggest something like fail2ban to attain this goal.